# Using async calls data in non-async Javascript, Node to javascript variable copy

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am fairly new to async scripts, I encountered a situation where our code is using an api through node.js, the api documentation provide the following usage, and it does work in a js file executed with nodejs.

```
var allpermissionsofthisEmployee = employee.permissions({ appId: cuurrappid });
allpermissionsofthisEmployee .then(console.log);
//this shows a json array of json objects on console.
function function2(permissioninfo) {
//Some code to work on this info
//ideally allow saving of part of that json object into MSSQLDB
}
```

What we have to do is, some how collect information that is being displayed on console into a variable and pass that to function2.

Comment: I understand that this might be answered a thousand times, but to a person like me(very little knowledge about async programming) all those answers are too generic or too specific. Also we need this as a proof of concept to actually start using that api.

Comment: the appid and cuurrappid are javascript varables and contain information about Our WebApplication.

Comment: `this shows a json array of json objects on console` .. so is it a string (JSON) or a plain javascript array of objects with no connection to JSON at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX it is just showing on the console, 
structure is and array of JSON objects, 
[{xyz:lorem ipsum}, {abc: lorem ipsum dolor sit}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `function2` instead of `console.log`. `then` take a function as callback and execute it. You need to read more about [`using promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```
var allpermissionsofthisEmployee = employee.permissions({ appId: cuurrappid });
allpermissionsofthisEmployee.then(function2);

function function2(permissioninfo) {
  // Some code to work on this info
  // ideally allow saving of part of that json object into MSSQLDB
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example, for data access in function2, how do i send the results as parameters to function2, 

thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: how can he write the code for you if only you know the content of `permissioninfo`

Comment: Not the code inside the function2, I want to know how to send parameter to function2. in the line,.
    allpermissionsofthisEmployee.then(function2);

Comment: if `permissions` are already printed on your `console` then they are already getting passed to `function2`

Comment: Thanks, this worked, 
 var allpermissionsofthisEmployee = employee.permissions({ appId: cuurrappid });
allpermissionsofthisEmployee.then((data) => {
      
        const allpermissionsofthisEmployeeforCurrentApp= data;
        function2(allpermissionsofthisEmployeeforCurrentApp, cuurrappid);
    });

function function2(permissioninfo, cuurrappid) {
  // Some code to work on this info
  // ideally allow saving of part of that json object into MSSQLDB
}


@VipinKumar, your solution helped a lot thanks